# Can't test event dispatching from disconnectedCallback

Tags: jestjs, lwc

I have got a LWC component with disconnectedCallback lifecycle hook function and wrote a test for it. The hook dispatches the 'disconnected' custom event. The test always fails, because the handler seems has never been called. What do I do wrong?

```js
export default class MyItem extends LightningElement {
  disconnectedCallback() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('disconnected', {bubbles: true}));
  }
}
```

The Jest test code:

```js
describe('c-my-item', () => {
  let element;
  beforeEach(() => {
    element = createElement('c-my-item', {is: MyItem});
    document.body.appendChild(element);
  });
  
  it('Test component removing', () => {
    const handler = jest.fn();
    document.addEventListener('disconnected', handler);
    document.body.removeChild(element);
    expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```